# Can someone please explain this bitwise program to me?

Tags: java, eclipse, binary, bitwise-operators

```
public class UpCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t;
        byte val;
        val = 123;
        for (t = 128; t > 0; t = t / 2) {
            System.out.println(t);
            if ((val & t) != 0) System.out.println(" 1");
            else System.out.println(" 0");
        }
    }
}
```

In particular, I am not sure why we are using `val=123`? I understand that this program will print out 123 in binary but why is that the case? How does this work? I do understand however, the principles of the `&` operator and how you can turn on and off bits but I am not sure how it works in this particular example?

Comment: start with those links. http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal and http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary

Comment: The best way to understand this code is to step through it one line at a time in your IDE debugger.  Hint: all it does is display the value of whatever is in `val` in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program will print out the binary digits of the number in `val` from MSB to LSB by comparing it to each power of 2:

```
123 : 01111011 &
128 : 10000000 = 
      00000000 

      00000000 != 0 => false, print 0

123 : 01111011 &
 64 : 01000000 = 
      01000000 

      01000000 != 0 =>  true, print 1

123 : 01111011 &
 32 : 00100000 = 
      00100000 

      00100000 != 0 =>  true, print 1

// repeat for 2^4-2^1... 

123 : 01111011 &
  1 : 00000001 = 
      00000001 

      00000001 != 0 =>  true, print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

It just checks if the value (123 in this case) using the bitwise operator &. The result of that is 1 or 0, this process is repeated for the following value 0.5t etc until t=0, resulting in the binary string for this value 123.